# Typical build size of the top 20 most popular frameworks?

Tags: builds, images

"Endless list" questions are a no no, so I limit to top 20 only.

I am presenting to non-dev ops people (even though I am one myself) on how some software we use creates quite a large image (~1.5 gb), and how other popular frameworks tend to be (although aren't always) smaller.

I googled for 'typical size of a flask app' (with the intention of repeating for other frameworks until I exhausted all that I know) and had trouble even finding that (these [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70198654/reducing-the-size-of-flask-app-docker-image#comment124092434_70198654) were somewhat useful, although possibly more related to the particulars of that user's question).

Is there a quick an easy info source listing the typical app size of, say, the top 20 most popular app frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of trying to discover the "typical" or "average" size of an app built with a particular framework, since this will be purely anecdotal and difficult to search for, you could instead search for some of the most popular applications with that framework and compare those sizes? As you stated in your question, some of these frameworks tend to be smaller, but depend entirely on the development team behind them.

Aside from the finding of the supporting information, I would also encourage you to talk about the benefits of having a smaller build, especially if your audience consists of non-dev ops people. Thinks to talk about would be shorter build times, better performance, code readability, fewer dependencies, quicker deployment times, etc. I think by starting your presentation with these kinds of talking points, you are solidifying the need for moving to a different type of framework.